# Granting specific permissions on ALL tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions, table

I have a tutorial that users need to type in PostgreSQL commands. I don't give the script to users simply because it's a learning experience. Everything in the script below is typed in except for the grants for table data, which is imported.

There should be a way to grant the permissions needed without having to include all the table names. If I can cut all that out I can have the users actually type the grant commands in instead id inserting from a script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
create database archive;

create database snort;

create user snort with password 'l0gg3r';

create user base with password 'an@l1st';

\connect archive;

\i d:/winids/barnyard2/schemas/create_postgresql;

\i d:/winids/inetpub/wwwroot/base/sql/create_base_tbls_pgsql.sql;

\i d:/winids/inetpub/wwwroot/base/sql/create_base_tbls_pgsql_extra.sql;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE data, detail, encoding, event, icmphdr, iphdr, opt, reference, reference_ref_id_seq, reference_system, reference_system_ref_system_id_seq, schema, sensor, sensor_sid_seq, sig_class, sig_class_sig_class_id_seq, sig_reference, signature, signature_sig_id_seq, tcphdr, udphdr, acid_ag, acid_ag_alert, acid_ip_cache, acid_event, base_roles, base_users TO base;

\connect snort;

\i d:/winids/barnyard2/schemas/create_postgresql;

\i d:/winids/inetpub/wwwroot/base/sql/create_base_tbls_pgsql.sql;

\i d:/winids/inetpub/wwwroot/base/sql/create_base_tbls_pgsql_extra.sql;

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLE data, detail, encoding, event, icmphdr, iphdr, opt, reference, reference_ref_id_seq, reference_system, reference_system_ref_system_id_seq, schema, sensor, sensor_sid_seq, sig_class, sig_class_sig_class_id_seq, sig_reference, signature, signature_sig_id_seq, tcphdr, udphdr TO snort;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE data, detail, encoding, event, icmphdr, iphdr, opt, reference, reference_ref_id_seq, reference_system, reference_system_ref_system_id_seq, schema, sensor, sensor_sid_seq, sig_class, sig_class_sig_class_id_seq, sig_reference, signature, signature_sig_id_seq, tcphdr, udphdr, acid_ag, acid_ag_alert, acid_ip_cache, acid_event, base_roles, base_users TO base;
```

Comment: You can check [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) which provides creating privilege definitions before creating object (such as tables) .

Answer (score 0):

If you're not specifying the table's schema, and you're not, then you can use `ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA` and rely on the default schema being `PUBLIC` or in the event you've changed your `search_path` just write the schema name below. From [the docs on `GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...]
         | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO role_specification [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

So that looks like

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE
  ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
  TO snort;
GRANT ALL
  ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
  TO base;
```